# can't fetch value of subscribed payload from paho client

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading, mqtt

i am runnig various mqtt clients in different threads and communicating the  clients with the broker.I am also emulating sensor data in the form of different threads and firing them in random times (normally in milliseconds or few second).I am posting the code below where i am facing the problem.The issue is the payload message is not always getting accessed (the subscribed message data).The payload is showing blank when copying it to a string.

```
       {
           std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(sub_mtx);
           msg_strm<<(char *) message->payload;
           sub_msg=msg_strm.str();
      }
    std::cout<<sub_msg<<std::endl;
```

// }

```
int remaining_lngth;

if(message->qos !=0){
    std::cout<<"QOS IS NOT ZERO HERE"<<std::endl;
    remaining_lngth=2+topicLen+2+message->payloadlen;
} else{
    remaining_lngth=2+topicLen+message->payloadlen;
}

//   std::cout<<"YOUR PAYLOAD SUBSCRIBED IS"<< sub_msg<<std::endl;
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(sub_mtx);
    std::cout << "PUBLISH MESSAGE LENGTH IS" << message->payloadlen << std::endl;
    sub_dmp_pkt_strm << "Message Type :  8" << "\n";
    sub_dmp_pkt_strm << "Duplicate Flag :" << message->dup << "\n";
    sub_dmp_pkt_strm << "QoS Level : " << message->qos << "\n";
    sub_dmp_pkt_strm << "RETAIN Flag : " << message->retained << "\n";
    sub_dmp_pkt_strm << "Remaining Length :" << remaining_lngth << "\n";
    sub_dmp_pkt_strm << "Topic Name String Length (MSB) : 0 " << "\n";
    sub_dmp_pkt_strm << "Topic Name String Length (LSB) : " << topicLen << "\n";
    sub_dmp_pkt_strm << "Topic Name : " << topicName << "\n";
    sub_dmp_pkt_strm << "Message ID (MSB) : " << message->msgid << "\n";
    sub_dmp_pkt_strm << "Message ID (LSB) : 0 " << "\n";
    sub_dmp_pkt_strm << "Publish Message : " + sub_msg + "\n";
    sub_dmp_pkt = sub_dmp_pkt_strm.str();
    log_packet_event(clnt_id, "SUBSCRIBE", sub_dmp_pkt.c_str(), remaining_lngth);
}
```

i am then writing the whole packet format in the database .